# Find unused IPv6 In an Address Range

Tags: mysql

How can I find the min unused IPv6 Addresses within the range `2001:48a8::1 to 2001:48a8::ffff` NOT IN a particular MySQL Table of used ips?

The issue I keep running into is the inability to do math on a `varbinary(16)`

My whole idea is something like:

```
SELECT MIN(IpAddress)+1
FROM IpAddresses t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM IpAddresses AS t2
    WHERE t2.IPAddress = t1.IPAddress+1
    AND t2.AddressRangeID = ?)
```

But that would only work if I could actually do math with the `varbinary(16)`.

Comment: I tried `CAST(HEX(IpAddress) AS DECIMAL(39))` but this is mysteriously truncating to just 6 digits.

Comment: An IPv6 address is a 128 bit address, which is what makes this so hard.

Comment: Can I ask what you're using the result for?

Answer (score 2):

Normally IP address ranges are generally checked using bitmasks.

```
2001:48a8::5 & FFFF:FFFF::0 = 2001:48a8::0  # in range
2002:48a8::5 & FFFF:FFFF::0 == 2002:48a8::0  # out of range
```

Unfortunately while [bitwise operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html) in MySQL work on binary types, they do so by converting to 64 bit big integers, not the 128 bits required by an IPv6 address.

Fortunately we can use string functions on VARBINARY data. [`LEFT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_left) performs the same function as a bitmask.

```
LEFT(2001:48a8::5, 4) = 200148a8  # in range
LEFT(2002:48a8::5, 4) = 200248a8  # out of range
```

It's `LEFT(x, 4)` and not `LEFT(x, 8)` because each hex character represents 16 bits, so two of them make a 32 bit character.

Put it all together like so.

```
SELECT HEX(IpAddress), HEX(LEFT(IpAddress, 4))
FROM   IpAddresses
WHERE  LEFT(IpAddress, 4) = UNHEX("200148A8");
```

---

You asked for the minimum IPs *not* in the range.  Since you can't do math on varbinary I would suggest simply getting the max in range and doing the math outside of SQL.

```
SELECT HEX(MAX(IpAddress))
FROM   IpAddresses
WHERE  LEFT(IpAddress, 4) = UNHEX("200148A8");
```

If you *really* want to do it, here's how.

You can't work on the full address, but you can work on just the lowest 64 bits.  You can get this with `RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)`.  Then it needs to be converted from binary to hex to an integer.  THEN you can do math on it.

```
CONV(HEX(RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10) + 1
```

Once you've done that it has to be put back together with the left hand side.  To do that it has to be converted back into a hex representation and padded out to 16 digits.

```
B -> 0000000000000000000000000000000B
LPAD( HEX(CONV(HEX(RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10) + 1), 32, '0' )
```

Finally, concatenate with the left side.

```
CONCAT(
    HEX(LEFT(IpAddress, 8)),
    LPAD(
        HEX(CONV(HEX(RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10) + 1),
        32, '0'
    )
)
```

Change `IpAddress` to `MAX(IpAddress)` in both places and you've got your next IP address.

To preserve everyone's sanity, I'd recommend putting all that into a stored procedure.

I leave it as an exercise to deal with a NULL result (hint: use a CASE).

Comment: Can you think of a way to split a `varbin(16)` into 2 big ints?

Comment: @Pachonk Yes, `CONV(HEX(LEFT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10)` and `CONV(HEX(RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10)`.

Comment: What about a case to add one to right, but if it's already full, then add it to the left? Also to get them back into varbin?

Comment: `CONCAT(CONV(CONV(HEX(LEFT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10), 10, 16), CONV(CONV(HEX(RIGHT(IpAddress, 8)), 16, 10), 10, 16))` just need that to go to varbin

Comment: @Pachonk I've got it. I edited my answer. It's such a mess I highly recommend you just get the highest IP address in the range (or NULL) and do the increment outside of SQL.

Comment: The last step, is how do I get it back to a VARBIN?

Comment: Also, smallest IP NOT USED in range.

Comment: @Pachonk Sorry, I think I've had my fill of this answer. [This article describes how to find missing entries in a range](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql/).